# web request run at Excel launch time in Excel AddIn

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, xll, excel-dna

I have an Excel AddIn,  when Excel launches, it will access a web service (GET), it is a simple web service request and should finish immediately says: something like `https://mywebservice.com&application=myapp&user=currentuser`, the result is a short (<200bytes) `JSON` expression.
If I run the request in brower, it is real quick as expected.

In my AddIn, I recorded the time from start to end of the web request, frequently (about 40-50% of time) it takes 3-5 seconds, other times, it is real quick as run from brower.

When it is slow, Excel has no response, simply show "Registering MyaddIn.xll..." in status bar.

I am so confused and not sure how to debug/fix the issue.

thanks

Here is C# I use to call web service

```
        private static int DownloadInfoFromServer(string entUrl, string localFilename)
    {
        // Function will return the number of bytes processed
        // to the caller. Initialize to 0 here.
        int bytesProcessed = 0;

        // Assign values to these objects here so that they can
        // be referenced in the finally block
        Stream remoteStream = null;
        Stream localStream = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        HttpWebRequest request;
        // Use a try/catch/finally block as both the WebRequest and Stream
        // classes throw exceptions upon error
        try
        {
            //clear out local file every time no matter request fails or not
            localStream = File.Create(localFilename);

            request = ServiceBase.GetHttpWebRequestWithProxyForEnt(entUrl);
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // Once the WebResponse object has been retrieved,
            // get the stream object associated with the response's data
            remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            if (remoteStream != null)
            {
                // Allocate a 1k buffer
                var buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                // Simple do/while loop to read from stream until
                // no bytes are returned
                do
                {
                    // Read data (up to 1k) from the stream
                    bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    // Write the data to the local file
                    localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    // Increment total bytes processed
                    bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
                } while (bytesRead > 0);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Helper.LogError(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null) response.Close();
            if (remoteStream != null) remoteStream.Close();
            if (localStream != null) localStream.Close();
        }

        // Return total bytes processed to caller.
        return bytesProcessed;
    }
```

Comment: Which event of the Excel AddIn do you use to call this download method ?

Comment: I am using Excel DNA to code my addin. It is not Excel event. It is in AutoOpen. It runs when Excel starts.

Comment: does this happen on different systems/logins or all on the same system+login?

Comment: then I suspect either a network problem or a race condition in the AddIn code... do have some detailed logs ?